# Html elements positioning in Rappid/Joint

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

I am working on a project where user can create flowcharts but the nodes in the chart need to be dynamic.  Basically they are HTML cards. For this approach I was following this: https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements 
But I am facing problems using this approach:

1. When paper resizes the absolute positioning changes and the html-element is not not on the top of svg element.How to solve this issue?
   [image]
2. There is use case where I need to grow the card dynamically, basically the inspector properties should be inside the card. But all the properties should not be shown at once. This means when the card grows,I will need to shift all the elements. How to achieve this?

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning for layouts. This will only work for one screen size.

Comment: Actually its absolute relative to paper which is perfectly placed in a scrollable container